# Material table with *ngFor with displayedColumns as array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to create table to render all columns with display columns as {key: string, display: string} where display is header and key is used to display value.

```
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of displayedColumns">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ renderHeader(col.display) }} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col.key] }} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

But as a result i get error:

```
    UniversalTableComponent.html:2 ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "[object Object]".
    at getTableUnknownColumnError (table.js:890)
    at table.js:1973
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)
    at MatTable._getCellTemplates (table.js:1965)
    at MatTable._renderRow (table.js:1920)
    at table.js:1779
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at MatTable._forceRenderHeaderRows (table.js:1774)
    at MatTable.ngAfterContentChecked (table.js:1251)
    at callProviderLifecycles (core.js:32324)
```

Comment: the problem is more bellow of your code. You has a line like `<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>` this "displayedColumns must be an array of string, so you need **two arrays**, one to feed the mat-header-row and another one to make the `*ngFor="let col of displayedColumns"

Answer (score 0):

displayedColumns is an object You can *ngFor only for Array . Make sure its an array in displayedColumns.
If u want to access the key only then Try element[displayedColumns.key] and remove *ngFor

Answer (score 0):

In fact, two lists are required.

```html
export interface ColumnaDataTable {
    columna: string;
    label: string;
}

  displayedColumns: ColumnaDataTable[] = [{ columna: 'clase', label: 'Clase' }];
  displayedColuXXX: string[] = [];
  
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows>
  <ng-container matColumnDef={{displayedColumn.columna}} class="make-gold"
    *ngFor="let displayedColumn of displayedColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{displayedColumn.label}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[displayedColumn.columna] }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColuXXX"></tr>
  <tr mat-row [ngClass]="{'make-gold': row.symbol == 'H'}" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColuXXX;">
  </tr>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
```